# gawk floating-point number localization

Tags: localization, awk, gawk

I want gawk to parse number using comma `,` as the decimal point character.
So I set `LC_NUMERIC` to `fr_FR.utf-8` but it does not work:

```
echo 123,2 | LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.utf-8 gawk '{printf ("%.2f\n", $1 + 0) }'
123.00
```

The solution is to specify option `--posix` or `export POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` but in this case the GNU awk extensions are not available, for example `delete` or the `gensub` function:

```
echo 123,2 | LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.utf-8 gawk --posix '{printf ("%.2f\n", $1 + 0) }'
123,20
```

Is it possible to have gawk parsing number with `,` as decimal point without specifying 
POSIX option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option your are looking for is:

> **--use-lc-numeric**
>
> This forces gawk to use the locale's decimal point character when parsing input data.  Although the POSIX standard requires this
> behavior, and gawk does so when --posix is in effect, the default is
> to follow traditional  behavior  and  use  a  period as the decimal
> point, even in locales where the period is not the decimal point
> character. This option overrides the default behavior, without the
> full draconian strictness of the --posix option.

**Demo:**

```
$ echo 123,2 | LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.utf-8 awk --use-lc-numeric '{printf "%.2f\n",$1}'
123,20
```

*Notes: `printf` is statement not a function so the parenthesis are not required and I'm not sure why you are adding zero here?*

Comment: The "+ 0 " was to force conversion from string to number ... but not required here, I guess printf do it anyway to format $1 as a number.