# Arithmetic operations with awk

Tags: macos, awk

I am trying to use awk to modify the first column of this file:

```
0.947250   0.000000 0.001000 0.015500 0.177000 0.806500
0.971700   0.000000 0.000100 0.005000 0.102900 0.892000
0.985701   0.000000 0.000000 0.001200 0.054795 0.944006
0.994251   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.022998 0.977002
0.996850   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.012599 0.987401
0.998150   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.007399 0.992601
0.998800   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.004800 0.995200
0.999250   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.003000 0.997000
0.999450   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.002200 0.997800
0.999750   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.001000 0.999000
```

I would need to transform the values in the first column in 1-value, leaving the other columns unchanged. I am trying the command

```
awk '{ x=1.-$1; print x,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' in_file > out_file
```

but this gives me

```
1  0.000000 0.001000 0.015500 0.177000 0.806500
1  0.000000 0.000100 0.005000 0.102900 0.892000
1  0.000000 0.000000 0.001200 0.054795 0.944006
1  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.022998 0.977002
1  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.012599 0.987401
1  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.007399 0.992601
1  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.004800 0.995200
1  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.003000 0.997000
1  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.002200 0.997800
1  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.001000 0.999000
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried different statements, but none worked. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

**Update**

Looks like the problem was with my version of `awk` (I am using `awk` version 20070501 on OSX 10.9.5) and not with the syntax. In fact, I downloaded `gawk` and now everything seems to be fine. So the question should maybe be why my awk seems to not be working correctly...

Comment: I can not reproduce this with GNU `awk`, with the default `awk` on OS X, or with `nawk` from NetBSD. What `awk` are you using on what operating system?

Comment: @Kusalananda I am using the default awk on OSX: version 20070501, OSX 10.9.5

Comment: I have the same `awk`, but on OS X 10.11.5. I don't have access to OS X 10.9.5 so I can't test this... But your command definitely works the way you want on my Mac.

Comment: @Kusalananda This is really annoying. What could be the problem? Should I try and update awk?

Comment: You could try installing GNU `awk`. It's available with [Homebrew](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/).

Comment: I don't know if the `awk` on older versions of OS X was compiled differently. Testing with another `awk` would be good, just to make sure there's nothing in the shell environment that screws things up for you.

Comment: @Kusalananda I installed gawk and now it works!

Comment: @EdMorton Assign x the value of one minus whatever is in the first field.

Comment: @Ed Morton Just what Kusalananda said. I just wanted to write it that way.

Comment: @Ed Morton I just eneded up with this expression because nothing was working ok? It is a perfectly good expression and in fact it works for Kusalananda and it works with gawk. 1. = 1.0, I thought it was pretty clear.

Comment: @EdMorton It's fairly common practice to try to promote an int to a float by explicitly providing the decimal point. He was having problems with `1-$1` (getting integer 1s), so he tried `1.-$1`.  What's random about that? It's just like saying `$string + 0` to force a language to interpret `$string` as a number. A perfectly reasonable thing to try.

Comment: @EdMorton I used this example because it was what I needed to do. Also I didn't know what the problem was of course, so in these cases it is difficult to make a good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your awk is behaving correctly, the problem is your locale setting which currently is using `,` instead of `.` as the decimal point and that contradicts your data so the string `0.5` will be treated as `0` in numerical operations since the intended number would have been `0,5`.

Use:

```
LC_ALL=C awk '{$1=1-$1}1' in_file > out_file
```

instead (or export LC_ALL=C in your environment to use that setting for all commands) and see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763/133219 for information on locales and `LC_ALL`.

Answer (score 4):

By default `awk` prints all the fields with the `print` command. Below would suffice :

```
awk '{$1=1-$1;print}' in_file > out_file
```

**Edit :** Based on [[ @ed-morton's ]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) comment to [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38540226/1620779) answer :

Sometimes awk can behave in an unexpected way if the locale is not C (or POSIX, which should be the same).

```
LC_ALL_OLD="$LC_ALL"
LC_ALL=C
awk '{$1=1-$1;print}' in_file > out_file
LC_ALL="$LC_ALL_OLD"
```

---

**Reference**

[[ What does LC_ALL=C  do? ]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87745/25919)

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, it does not work if I use awk. But it works perfectly if I use gawk.

Comment: @valerio92 : What is the error when you tried the above?

Comment: @valerio92 : Could you post the result of `ls -l $(which gawk)` and `ls -l $(which awk)` please

Comment: `lrwxr-xr-x  1 Valerio  admin    29B 23 Lug 11:25 /usr/local/bin/gawk@ -> ../Cellar/gawk/4.1.1/bin/gawk` (which gawk) ; `-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   106K 28 Giu  2014 /usr/bin/awk*` (which awk)

Comment: @valerio92 : I suspect this to be a bug with awk, Now you have installed `gawk` you may remove the `awk` completely and link awk to gawk

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: @valerio92 : I'm not a Mac User, so I dunno how you uninstall packages. In case you need help, check [\[ this \]](http://apple.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. I guess I could also leave awk there and just use gawk.

Comment: @valerio92 : I saw ed's comment for your answer and saw that `locale` is the villain.. See the edit..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem installing `gawk` on my mac (OSX 10.9.5). For some reason my `awk` implementation was not working correctly.

```
gawk '{ x=1.-$1; print x,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' in_file > out_file
```

The output is now correct:

```
0.05275 0.000000 0.001000 0.015500 0.177000 0.806500
0.0283 0.000000 0.000100 0.005000 0.102900 0.892000
0.014299 0.000000 0.000000 0.001200 0.054795 0.944006
0.005749 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.022998 0.977002
0.00315 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.012599 0.987401
0.00185 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.007399 0.992601
0.0012 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.004800 0.995200
0.00075 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.003000 0.997000
0.00055 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.002200 0.997800
0.00025 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.001000 0.999000
```

Also with different statements:[image]

([Installing gawk on mac](http://macappstore.org/gawk/))

Comment: @Ed Morton x=1-$1 does not work either, and 1.=1.0. I thought that was clear. Also if my expression is so meaningless why does it work exactly like I want it to in gawk?

Comment: @valerio92: See [\[ this \]](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do)

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with comments that locale is a likely culprit, OP could be using any of various locales where "." is not a decimal separator.  For instance,

```
LC_ALL=it_IT.UTF-8 ./foo.sh;cat out_file
```

gives me (same version of BSD-awk):

```
1 0.000000 0.001000 0.015500 0.177000 0.806500
1 0.000000 0.000100 0.005000 0.102900 0.892000
1 0.000000 0.000000 0.001200 0.054795 0.944006
1 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.022998 0.977002
1 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.012599 0.987401
1 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.007399 0.992601
1 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.004800 0.995200
1 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.003000 0.997000
1 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.002200 0.997800
1 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.001000 0.999000
```

while

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 ./foo.sh;cat out_file
```

gives me

```
0.05275 0.000000 0.001000 0.015500 0.177000 0.806500
0.0283 0.000000 0.000100 0.005000 0.102900 0.892000
0.014299 0.000000 0.000000 0.001200 0.054795 0.944006
0.005749 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.022998 0.977002
0.00315 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.012599 0.987401
0.00185 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.007399 0.992601
0.0012 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.004800 0.995200
0.00075 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.003000 0.997000
0.00055 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.002200 0.997800
0.00025 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.001000 0.999000
```

Further reading:

- [How to change the decimal separator with awk/sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439001/how-to-change-the-decimal-separator-with-awk-sed)
- [gawk floating-point number localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832395/gawk-floating-point-number-localization)
- [6.6 Where You Are Makes a Difference](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Locales.html) (Gawk reference)